# What is the class to refer a calendar SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, css, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to find out which class refers to a calendar in SharePoint 2013. I have tried '`.ms-acal`', but no luck. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I am working on a Ajax code to refresh the calendar webpart after the document.ready function, so for that reason i need to be able to

- Identify if the page has a calendar WebPart on it
- If it does, apply the Ajax functionality to that control using its `ID`
  or `CLASS`

Comment: Use browser developer tool to find the html element and its associated styles.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: Aakash i have update the question with an EDIT

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do. However, you can use:

Calendar Header

```
ms-acal-header
```

Calendar Body

`ms-acal-rootdiv`

Comment: I am trying to refresh the calendar web part if the page contains one., so for that purpose i want to be able to identify that there is a calendar webpart on the page

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the following `ID` also

```
AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView
```

This is the ID of the Parent div of div having following class

```
ms-acal-header
```